# RuntimeError: Failed to init API, possibly an invalid tessdata path:<>

Tags: python-3.x, tesseract

I am using windows os. Want to detect the text from an image with fontAttributes by tesserocr. But when I am running the python code, I am getting this error - 
RuntimeError: Failed to init API, possibly an invalid tessdata path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata/

i) I have installed -

```
tesseract-ocr-w32-setup-v5.0.0-alpha.20190623.exe
//(though my system is 64 bit)
```

ii) Added to path variable (both system and user path) -

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR
C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata
```

iii) Created new system path variable - TESSDATA_PREFIX and linked path of

```
tessdata  folder, like -
TESSDATA_PREFIX - C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata


import pytesseract
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'C')

from tesserocr import PyTessBaseAPI, RIL, iterate_level,OEM


with PyTessBaseAPI(oem=OEM.TESSERACT_ONLY,lang='bask') as api:
    api.SetImageFile('sugar.png')

    api.Recognize()
    ri = api.GetIterator()
    level = RIL.WORD

    for r in iterate_level(ri, level):
        attrs = r.WordFontAttributes()
        symbol = r.GetUTF8Text(level)

        print(symbol,attrs)


 with PyTessBaseAPI(oem=OEM.TESSERACT_ONLY,lang='bask') as api:
 File "tesserocr.pyx", line 1168, in tesserocr._tesserocr.PyTessBaseAPI.__cinit
__
  File "tesserocr.pyx", line 1181, in tesserocr._tesserocr.PyTessBaseAPI._init_a
pi
RuntimeError: Failed to init API, possibly an invalid tessdata path: C:\Program
Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you don't have the .traineddata files in your system. you have to copy it from

> C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata

and paste all the data files to your directory , I'd suggest create a virtual environment ans then use it